# TFS extension, enable OK from within the dialog

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-extensions

TFS 2018u1. I'm putting together an extension with a custom host dialog. There are two contributions involved - the dialog page itself, which has type "ms.vss-web.control", and the custom menu item that opens the dialog.

The OK button on the dialog is disabled by default. [The guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/using-host-dialog?view=vsts) tells us to enable it by calling `updateOkButton()` on the dialog object, *which is returned from the `openDialog()` to the menu item script*.

But the dialog page itself is perfectly scriptable, too. Is there a way to get to the dialog object from the dialog page itself? It makes more sense to be to enable/disable the OK button from event handlers that live on the dialog page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by calling

```
VSS.getConfiguration().dialog.updateOkButton(true);
```

Comment: Caveat: VSS.getConfiguration() comes back as undefined immediately after `init()` and `register()`. It's a valid object later on.